# Improper merger

Tags: support, specific-question, merged-questions

The [recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/466677/when-did-optics-begin-to-mean-appearance-or-perception?noredirect=1) about the early usage of optics meaning  “point of view” has been improperly merged into an [older similar question.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80574/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-optics-thats-prevalently-used-now-in-politics)

Can you please restore the new original question?

Thanks.

Comment: +1 – Agreed: [The newer question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/466677/67775) even had a great accepted answer which is now missing!

Comment: Technically, the question was not deleted, since anyone (even anonymous users) can see it with the right link, so I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @feetwet The writer of the answer (and this question) deleted it himself. User240918, please edit this question to show the reasoning behind your assertion that the merge shouldn't have happened.

Comment: @user240918: Could you at least undelete your answer?  It was very helpful.  You can anonymize it if you don't want to own it.